# How to use PHP includes without changing the URL?

Tags: php, html, php-include

I've written a simple php page that when you click on one of the links it includes a different php file, thereby changing the content. Below is the code I have so far, the only problem is that each time you click on a link, the URL changes to index.php?page=page1, which doesn't look very good.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Includes </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is the home page </h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page1">Page1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page2">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page3">Page3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>


<div style='width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;'>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$page = $_GET['page'];
$pages = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        include($page);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return
        <a href="includes.php">home</a>';
    }
}
else {
    include('page1.php');
}
?>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do the same thing (just change the content), without changing the URL in the address bar?

Comment: how about Javascript ??

Comment: I don't really know any Javascript, so unless it's easy I just won't bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is reloading its own page with a reference to the content to be added. The $_GET method is the natural way to do this, but there are two other options which spring to mind.

1) Use a session variable to reference the page to be loaded.
2) Use AJAX so that the page is never actually reloaded. Instead, you load the new content into the page via AJAX.

If you want to go the session variable route, then something like this will do it.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_GET['page'])
  {
    // set session variable
    $_SESSION['page'] = $_GET['page'];
    // redirect to hide URL change
    header('Location: includes.php');
  }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Includes </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is the home page </h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page1">Page1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page2">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="includes.php?page=page3">Page3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>


<div style='width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;'>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$page = $_SESSION['page'];
$pages = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        include($page);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return
        <a href="includes.php">home</a>';
    }
}
else {
    include('page1.php');
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, that is exactly what I wanted and this is such a simple solution, no Javascript or Ajax required!

Answer (score 1):

Either stick with the GET method, and use your servers [mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) functionality to make a nicer looking url eg: `/page1`

OR

Use the POST method and send the arguments via form elements. Example:

```
<form action= '' method = POST>
<select name=page>
<option value=page1>Page 1</option>
</option>
<input type=submit />
</form>
```

Access the values then using $_POST instead of $_GET, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new request to process the php code. If the problem is only with URL address:

You can make a ajax/iframe request to keep the same address:

**Ajax**

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> PHP Includes </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadContent(page) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "includes.php?page=" + page,
                complete: function(response) {
                    $('#content').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is the home page </h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:loadContent('page1')">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:loadContent('page2')">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:loadContent('page3')">Page3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content" style='width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // loading default page
        loadContent('page1');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

includes.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$page = $_GET['page'];
$pages = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        include($page);
    } else {
        echo 'Page not found.
    }
} else {
    include('page1.php');
}
?>
```

**Iframe (without use of javascript)**

```
<li><a href="includes.php?page=page1" target="iframe_id">Page1</a></li>
```

OR you can make use of **friendly URL** (mod_rewrite in apache2):

```
<li><a href="includes/page1">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="includes/page2">Page2</a></li>
<li><a href="includes/page3">Page3</a></li>
```

more about friendly url [googling](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=mod_rewrite+example&oq=mod_rewrite+example&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.4445j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5821160854c2fd50&q=mod_rewrite+friendly+url+example)

Answer (score 0):

you can create 3 different divs on your page, then, when you click at one of this buttons, you hide ore show divs on javascript. You need to set id's for each div to call they corrrectly